# Adjust number of Rows to Form:: Textarea Laravel 5

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

How can I control the number of Rows added to a textarea using the `Illuminate\Html\FormFacade` class?

I have added the field into my template.

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('placeOfDeath','Place of Death') !!}
  {!! Form::textarea('placeOfDeath',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

When it gets rendered the textarea has `cols="50"` and `rows="10"`

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="placeOfDeath" cols="50" rows="10" id="placeOfDeath"></textarea>
```

I want a way to control these numbers, I have checked the documentation but couldnt spot anything?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The options (third parameter) array is actually the attributes array of that element, you so can just pass any `'key' => 'value'` and the element will have it as attributes, for example:

```
{!! Form::textarea('placeOfDeath',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'rows' => 2, 'cols' => 40]) !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have accepted the other answer as it works perfectly.

I have also found that the class actually checks for an attribute `size`

```
protected function setQuickTextAreaSize($options)
{
    $segments = explode('x', $options['size']);

    return array_merge($options, array('cols' => $segments[0], 'rows' => $segments[1]));
}
```

Its a minor space saving, Im not sure it makes the code anymore readable, but it is an alternative to cut off a few characters

```
['size' => '30x5']
```

Comment: I never thought of, extracting this to its own helper, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Also try this:

```
{!! Form::textarea('placeOfDeath',null, array('class'=>'form-control', 
                    'rows' => 10, 'cols' => 50)) !!}
```